# Advertising Hardware Recommendations - Community Ads for 2016

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, advertising

It's 2016, and the new 300px-wide sidebar has just rolled out network wide. When that's complete, graduated sites around the network will start to run new community ad cycles.

To be ready for them, let's start designing! Submit as answers on this post an ad that you'd like to see representing Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange to the rest of the network.

- Ads must now be **300px wide by 250px tall**.
- There's a limit on file size of 150 kB.
- The image must be hosted on i.stack.imgur.
- Ads must be GIF or PNG (no animated GIFs).
- You **can** resubmit ads from last time round, if you want to see them used again.
- When an ad reaches 6 votes *here*, feel free to take it and post in on the various community ad submission threads on other (preferably related) sites.

Let's advertise ourselves!

Comment: My favorite time of the year!